# unpaired low surrogate in loading json in python

Tags: python, json

I encounter a problem in loading a json file in python. My code looks like:

```
with open(file,'r') as infile:
     json.load(infile)
```

I have 10 files which should be in the same format. 
For 9/10 JSON files it works, but for one file it shows the error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unpaired low surrogate: line 1 column 27948557 (char 27948556)
```

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: You can't. Your JSON is malformed, it is missing half of a [UTF-16 surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B0000_to_U.2BD7FF_and_U.2BE000_to_U.2BFFFF).

Comment: try http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see if your json file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading simplejson to 3.6.5
and do simplejson.load(infile)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: simplejson version 3.3 and above have the low surrogate pairing solved